# Function that require high CPUs

Tags: aws-lambda, cloud, cpu, cloud-hosting, serverless

I have a piece of code that I need it to run as fast as possible. It is written in C# and I cannot change anything about that code (and jeez I don't want to).

I been given a task to make it work fast and cheap as possible.

Now so far I tried Digital Ocean servers, I found that there are optimized servers. It is running much better though I still couldn't make it be cheap as I wanted.

So far I was able to run it in ~4s in $160 server in DO (8 cores), it is actually running faster on my PC (16 cores).

Now I am new to all the cloud computing, but is there any cloud provider that can get me more CPU cores with less memory/networking for cheaper?

This code can run on 2GB memory machine in the same speed, I don't need 32GB .

I read about AWS Lambda, is it really faster? I didn't see anywhere that they publish CPU cores of their "server-less" servers.

Comment: Has the C# code been written to run in parallel on multiple CPUs? If not, then adding more CPUs won't make it run any faster. How is the C# code used -- I presume it is part of a bigger application? Or is it called directly?

Comment: it is written to run in paralle, i tested it on multiple servers, 
more CPU = much faster - it takes 100% of all the cpu cores and it called directly trough CLI command